# Android Draw Time

Tags: android, performance

Whats a Good Draw Time? Im getting around 30-35 MS when i look at it in HeirchyViewer

Comment: What are you drawing, how complicated it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

30-35ms is about 33fps, which most people would agree is rather appropriate for fastish-moving images.

It's up to you to decide whether 30fps is 'good'. If you've got other overheads to consider (for example, a game might spend 30ms/frame on rendering, 5ms on AI, 10ms on sound etc.) this might be too high. If this is a simple gallery application or text viewer, 30fps is more than enough!

Comment: Wow, 30fps is good, since Im just doing non-game stuff. The UI tree is a little complicated, for example there are eventually 5 ListViews on the screen at once each with a custom adapter, and when you get to that point its 30ms/frame. before its about 50/60 ms. So I think its pretty good. Im using ViewStubs so its helping a lot. Thanks for the ms to fps conversion. I was being dumb, i cant belive i overlooked that